# Set columns conditions while binding a large list of files

Tags: r, conditional-statements, large-files

I'm stuck. I have defined those lines of code in order to bind diferent csv that i read parsing its folders.

```
setAs("character", "myDate", function(from) as.Date(from, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))

LF <- list.files("O:/00 CREDIT MANAGEMENT/", pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)

PayMatrix <- do.call("rbind", lapply(archivos1, function(x) {
  read.csv(x, header = 3, sep = ";", dec = ",", skip = "2", na.strings = "", 
           colClasses= c("Expiration.Date" = "myDate", "Payment.date" = "myDate"))
}))
```

My problem is that it is a very large set of data, and I would like to know how to parsing this csv conditionally depending of the value of "Payment.Date" Column (i.e. Payment.Date>0), equally, I´m going to use only a few part of the columns in those csv so I will like to cut the files before or during the loop.

I´ve tried the "awk" thing, but it is not working.

```
{read.csv(pipe("awk '{if (Payment.date > 0) print [,c(1:2,6:9,29)]}'x"), header=3...
```

My input files are something similar to that. (csv, header=3)

```
            CURRENT INVOICES 27/03/2017 (W 13)  
            16276178,26 
Client Code.  Invoice   Invoice Date    Expiration Date Amount  Payment date
1004775     21605000689 29/05/2016        29/07/2016    226,3   
1005140     21702000548 28/02/2017        28/04/2017    22939,2 
1004775     21703005560 25/03/2017        25/05/2017    21456,2 
1004858     F9M01815.   30/01/2017        30/03/2017    5042,52 27/03/2017
```

Comment: The input file doesn't seem to match with the parameters of the call to `read.csv()`, in particular `sep = ";"`.

Answer (score 1):

Would a selection within the `lapply()` function work for you? (untested due to lack of reproducible example)

```
PayMatrix <- do.call("rbind", lapply(archivos1, function(x) {
  tmp <- read.csv(x, header = 3, sep = ";", dec = ",", skip = "2", na.strings = "", 
           colClasses= c("Expiration.Date" = "myDate", "Payment.date" = "myDate"))
  tmp[tmp$Payment.Date > 0, ]
}))
```

BTW: For handling large data frames efficiently, I recommend to consider to use the `data.table` package. With that, your code could become (untested)

```
library(data.table)
PayMatrix <- rbindlist(lapply(archivos1, function(x) {
  fread(x, <...>)[Payment.Date > 0, ]
}))
```

where <...> denote the parameters which have to be passed to `fread()`.

BTW: The `fread()` function in the `data.table` package is not just for speed on large files. It has very useful convenience features for small data. For details, please, see [`fread`'s wiki page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Convenience-features-of-fread).

Comment: Please just use data.table for large files, it's absolutely incomparable to base r in terms of efficiency and speed

Comment: @Alexvonrass Thank you for supporting my suggestion to use `data.table`!

Comment: Thanks. I´m unable to make Fread works...i cant fix the header an the skip lines...may because i have some irregular files. I am using rbindlist. I cant neither make the conditions as willing with your code, i cant make it to be recognised.

Comment: Please, can youe [edit] your Q and post the first 5 lines of your input file?

Comment: Thank you Uwe Block, I have posted an example of my input files

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodríguez Oh, yes, I can see why fread fails: It's because some column headers have blanks in it, e.g., `Client Code.` or `Payment date`. `fread()` has recognized that the columns are separated by blanks. So, it sees more column headers than columns. There are two options, I can think of: (1) reading with fixed field widths or (2) skip the row headers on read and rename the columns afterwards. Let me think this over, please...

Comment: Thank you Uwe, i´m still using read.csv due to the columns thing but not able to aplly conditionals

Comment: I have changed my read.csv function as in your example, by writing "tmp<-read.csv" instead of "read.csv" and adding "tmp[tmp$Payment.date > 0,]", but I get "unexpected symbol"